# Exchange multiple Cryptocurrencies

Tags: exchanges, currencies

Does anybody know a good exchange site for various cryptocurrencies like LTC, NMC, IXC, DVC, BTC etc.

One I found was Vircurex but it is very cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Cryptsy](https://www.cryptsy.com/) has a lot of currencies to trade. Right now you can only trade them one versus each other (BTC to LTC, NMC to BTC) but they are planning to start trading for USD.

You might find the interface cumbersome as well, but in my opinion it is still better then vircurex's.

Comment: The main problem I see with Cryptsy is that it's OH SO SLOOOOOOWWWWW!!!! Besides that, I don't find the interface that bad, and I actually like their allowing you to trade very small amounts of coins in more than 40+ different cryptocoins